# _.map overwriting value upon return

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I've been noticing some strange behaviour when using `lodash` `_.ma` function. (That or I'm blatantly overlooking something)

I have the following:

```
_this.searches = _.map(body.rows, function(row) {
    var tmpSearch = new Search(row.value);
    console.log(tmpSearch.search['name']);
    return tmpSearch.search;
});
```

`Search` is just a standard javascript object with some prototype functions.

However, when I inspect `_this.searches`, every object is the same, I tried to loop through it to get a better result:

```
_.forEach(_this.searches, function(search) {
    console.log(search['name']);
})
```

The `console.log` for the `_.map` is this:

```
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:35 () test
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:35 () Test 2
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:35 () Testing search
```

The `console.log` for the `_.forEach` is this:

```
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:42 () Testing search
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:42 () Testing search
2015-04-03T14:14:29+0800 <log> searches.js:42 () Testing search
```

The `Search` can be found here: http://pastebin.com/4y6taGUr
Although there's nothing special going on.

Comment: What is the structure of `body.rows` array? Is `row.value` an object or smth like string/integer value?

Comment: @Kiril `body.rows` is an array with objects, `row.value` is also an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in line:

```
Search.prototype.search = {};
```

As soon as you put the `search` property into the prototype of `Search` class - it's shared between all instances of `Search`. So every change of this property affects all instances. That's why you always see the last assigned value.
To fix it - put this property into the instance itself, e.g. in the constructor:

```
var Search = function(searchDoc) {
    this.search = {};
    if(!_.isEmpty(searchDoc)) this.setSearch(searchDoc);
};
```

See the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nifoxusive/1/).

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I overlooked that. That definitely sorted it out, thanks a lot!